# How to display meta_value only once if the value is the same

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have created a loop to display the meta value but wanted to show it only once if they are the same of value. I have tried using array_unique but it doesn't seem to work

```
   $query = new WP_Query( $args );    

  
  if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    $menusInList = [];
      while ( $_query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        $menu = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'awarded', true);
        if (in_array($menu, $menusInList)) {
        continue;
    }

    $menusInList[] = $menu;
          echo '<li class="'.$menus .'" >' . $menu . '</li>';
        }
          echo '</ul>';
        } else {
          // no posts found
        }
  /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: its `$menus = [];` not `$menus[];` after your `echo '<ul>';`

Comment: and it seems like you are using `$menus` already for your `<li class` so rename `$menus = []` to `$menusInList = [];` aswell as `$menusInList[] = $menu;` and `in_array($menu, $menusInList)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save `$menu` in an array `$menusInList` and check via [`in_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php). if it returns true use `continue`to skip.

```
$menusInList = [];
while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $query->the_post();
    $menu = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'award', true);

    if (in_array($menu, $menusInList)) {
        continue;
    }

    $menusInList[] = $menu;

    // ...

}
```

Comment: I have update the code on the thread with your code however when I do that, I get a fatal error

Comment: I commented your question :)